# Show a list in a page, then replace each list item one by one with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple list in my page:

```
<ul id="alphabet" >
   <li><span>A</span></li>
   <li><span>B</span></li>
   <li><span>C</span></li>
   <li><span>D</span></li>
</ul>
```

etc.

I want the page to load so the user can see this list, then replace each item one by one from a different list using jQuery. I have the new items stored in an array that I go through:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var newSkillArray = ["ANDROID DEV", 
                     "BOOTSTRAP", 
                     "CSS", 
                     "DATABASES"]
```

etc.

This jQuery code makes the individual, new, listitems show up OK but for some reason when I load the page, the list has already changed - and then the loop runs again.

```
$("li").each(function (index){
$(this).delay(2000).fadeOut(100);
$(this).delay(400*index).text(newSkillArray[index]);
$(this).delay(400*index).fadeIn(300);
});
```

I want the original list to show, then run my loop. Do I need a queue? I don't really understand how to do that. Thank you for any help.

Working JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wkbe6zjw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would go like this:

```
var index = 0;
var lis = $("li");
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  console.log($("li")[index]);
  lis.eq(index).fadeOut(400, function() {
    $(this).text(newSkillArray[index]).fadeIn(400);
  });
  index++;
  if (index == newSkillArray.length) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 600);
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Shitsu/tr30kvk3/1/. The transitions are smooth and nice.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking to create! Do you have any resources that I can seek out to improve my jquery? I've done basic coursework on selectors, animations etc but I am looking to learn more... thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Check this fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/wkbe6zjw/4/

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="alphabet" class="show-for-medium-up show-for-landscape">
  <li><span>A</span></li>
  <li><span>B</span></li>
  <li><span>C</span></li>
  <li><span>D</span></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var newSkillArray = ["ANDROID DEV", 
                    "BOOTSTRAP", 
                    "CSS", 
                    "DATABASES"];
    $("li").each(function (index){
        var li = $(this);
        li.fadeOut(2000);
        window.setTimeout(function () {
          li.text(newSkillArray[index]).delay(400*index).fadeIn(300);
        }, 2000);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
function FadeIn() {
var newSkillArray = ["ANDROID DEV", 
                    "BOOTSTRAP", 
                    "CSS", 
                    "DATABASES"];
//debugger;
    $("li").each(function (index){
    $(this).delay(0).fadeOut(0);
    $(this).delay(400*index).text(newSkillArray[index]);
    $(this).delay(400*index).fadeIn(300);
    });
}

// document ready
$(function() {
    setTimeout(FadeIn, 2000);
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yqx2w5n4/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var newSkillArray = ["ANDROID DEV", 
                    "BOOTSTRAP", 
                    "CSS", 
                    "DATABASES"];
//debugger;
    $("li span").each(function (index){
    $(this).delay(2000*index).fadeOut(100, function(){
     $(this).text(newSkillArray[index]);
    $(this).delay(400*index).fadeIn(300);
    });

    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wkbe6zjw/5/

Comment: the first one jumps awkwardly but the second one is nice!

Comment: @perrysetgo well you could at least give me some credit by voting up